# "Inaccurate" means "completely wrong"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence

I wonder if you could tell me, the word "inaccurate" means "completely wrong" or "Not precise"?
For example, consider the following sentence:
Your estimation is inaccurate.

Comment: It is not possible to answer your question without your giving an example in context. The importance of context, in English, cannot be overstated.

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy and precision have different meanings. A set of measurements is precise if the measurements are all close to each other, even if thay are all far from the true value.  The set is accurate if the mean (average) is close to the true value, even if there is significan spread in their values. Obviously an experimenter will try to be both accurate and precise.

An inaccurate result may still be useful, depending on the amount of error that is acceptable in a particular situation. For example the Earth's gravity is usually given as 9.8 metre per second squared, but the inaccurate value of 10 is often used when it is accurate enough.

Comment: My favourite examples to illustrate the difference between precision and accuracy are clocks: If I have two (digital) clocks, one displaying the current time as "10:41" and the other as "10:42:17.2", then the letter has a much higher *precision* as it allows me to read off the time in tenths of seconds (if I can read fast enough) instead of only up ot minutes. But if the "true" current time is "10:40:53.9856729846", then the first clock has a higher accuracy.

Comment: Thank you very much. The example of gravity was really helpful.